# If a post has two categories with different permissions, what will happen?

Tags: categories

I have a category that(using a plugin) is member only. What happens if a post is given a category that is member only, and a category that is available to everyone? If it is still accessible to everyone, how can I prevent that?

Comment: Depends on how your plugin manages this. Since a) we don't know the name of the plugin and b) are not plugin support, well, this is impossible to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested it, and by default it will show it to everyone even if one of the categories is member only. If you need a fix for that(like me), then use the following in `functions.php`:

```
function my_filter( $content ) {

    $categories = array(
        'news',
        'opinions',
        'sports',
        'other',
    );

    if ( in_category( $categories ) ) {
        if ( is_logged_in() ) {
            return $content;
        } else {
            $content = '<p>Sorry, this post is only available to members</p>';
            return $content;
        }
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_filter' );
```

from my other [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274296/how-can-i-only-show-certain-posts/).