# How can I only show certain posts?

Tags: categories, membership

How can I make it so only members see post summaries on category pages? Currently only members can access them, but they still show up on category pages for non members.

Note: I now made a plugin for this, you can get it at: https://github.com/NerdOfLinux/MemberOnly

Comment: So you need all category views to be block or just one/few?

Comment: I need for member only posts to not show up for non members.

Comment: So it's a single category called something like `members-only`?

Comment: No, I have categories that I need both members and non members to access, I just want to hide some posts from non members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't had time to test this, but you can probably do this with the `the_content` filter hook. This way you won't have to insert this code into `archive.php`, `category.php`, `tag.php`, `author.php` and any other archive file depending on how your theme is structured.

In your theme's `functions.php` file add the following:

```
function my_filter( $content ) {

    $categories = array(
        'news',
        'opinions',
        'sports',
        'other',
    );

    if ( in_category( $categories ) ) {
        if ( is_logged_in() ) {
            return $content;
        } else {
            $content = '<p>Sorry, this post is only available to members</p>';
            return $content;
        }
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_filter' );
```

So what this could should do is intercept the content of the post between when it's pulled from the database and it's displayed. Then it's going to check and see if the post has one of the categories listed in the `$categories` array (NOTE: It's best to use the category *slug* here in the array). Then it will see if the user is logged in.

If they are, then it will display the post. If they are not, then it will set the content to the message and then send that back in place of the post's content.

If the user is logged in, or the post is not in any of those categories in the array, then it will return the post as normal.

NOTE: If you're using `the_excerpt()` in your theme instead of `the_content()`, then simply change the hook in the `add_filter()` call to `'the_excerpt'` and it should work.

Comment: I added it to my `functions.php` file, but it still isn't working. I changed `is_logged_in` to `is_user_logged_in` because that was what I found in the wordpress documentation. I tried both `the_excerpt` and `the_content`. I'm, using the twenty seventeen theme by the way.

Comment: I fixed it. Just change `is_category` to `in_category`. From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515732/wordpress-category-if-condition-not-working

Comment: Sorry about the function typos. Thanks for catching and fixing them.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of thing, I prefer to work within templates rather than in `functions.php`. This way, you don't need an additional `if` statement to determine what category you are applying the conditions to. You can apply this method to all categories using the `category.php` template or create custom templates for individual categories if you want to display different content in different categories. Personally, I find using templates for this kind of work makes it easier see what I'm doing.

In your case, you wou create an `if` statement like the example above with the `is_user_logged_in` tag before whatever your want to reveal to your members. Then add an `else` for whatever you want to display instead when a user is not logged in before closing the statement.

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    the_excerpt(); // or whatever
} else {
    echo '<p>This information is for members only.</p>'; // or whatever 
}?>
```

Comment: The problem with working in the template files themselves is that he would need to insert the code multiple times depending on how his theme is structured. If he only had `archive.php` then it would be fine, but he'd have the same problem again if there were `tags.php`, 'author.php`, etc. Using the filter would catch it everywhere.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there are advantages and disadvantages to each method. It seemed the OP was having difficulty implementing your solution, so I suggested another approach that might be easier him/her.

Comment: The solution I proposed would be more DRY is a separate loop was made and added to each template requiring it.

Comment: How is it DRY when you have to put it into every template file? The solution I proposed will occur on every template file. His difficulties came from typos I made and didn't catch.

Comment: What I wrote about was making a separate loop, not adding that code to every template. By that I mean creating a separate file with that code in it and adding it to template files as needed with `get_template_part`. I apologize if I created any confusion.

Comment: And it looks like s/he figured it out and accepted your solution. So, well done!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the post id's store them in an array and then display them one by one.

```
  <?php $thePostIdArray = array("28","74", "82", "92"); ?>
  <?php $limit = 4 ?>
  <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $counter++; ?>
  <?php if ( $counter < $limit + 1 ): ?>
  <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  <?php $post_id = $thePostIdArray[$counter-1]; ?>
  <?php $queried_post = get_post($post_id); ?>
  <h2><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?></h2>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```