# How to get post URL in the_content filter?

Tags: plugins, php, functions

In WordPress, I use a function in functions.php to only not show certain posts(by category) if a user is not signed in:

```
   function my_filter( $content ) {

    $categories = array(
        'news',
        'opinions',
        'sports',
        'other',
    );

    if ( in_category( $categories ) ) {
        if ( is_logged_in() ) {
            return $content;
        } else {
            $content = '<p>Sorry, this post is only available to members</p> <a href="gateblogs.com/login"> Login </a>';
            return $content;
        }
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_filter' );
```

I use a plugin(not important to my question), but basically, I can use something like `https://gateblogs.com/login?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fgateblogs.com%2Ftechnology%2Flinux-tutorials%2Fsending-mail-from-server` to redirect to a page after a successful login. How can I get a post's URL and apply it into the sign up link.

Note: The function is originally from [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274296/how-can-i-only-show-certain-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it with the `get_the_permalink()` function:

```
/* Protect Member Only Posts*/
function post_filter( $content ) {

    $categories = array(
        'coding',
        'python',
        'linux-tutorials',
        'swift',
        'premium',
    );
    if ( in_category( $categories ) ) {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            return $content;
        } else {
            $link = get_the_permalink();
            $link = str_replace(':', '%3A', $link);
            $link = str_replace('/', '%2F', $link);
            $content = "<p>Sorry, this post is only available to members. <a href=\"gateblogs.com/login?redirect_to=$link\">Sign in/Register</a></p>";
            return $content;
        }
    } else {
         return $content;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'post_filter' );
```

Please note than the `str_replace` is because I has to change the link for the plugin to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a conditional and return the post's URL by using a `get_the_permalink()` in conjunction with `is_single()`:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_filter' );

function my_filter( $content ) {

     // Check if we're inside the main loop in a single post page.
    if ( is_single() && in_the_loop() && is_main_query() ) {
        return $content . get_the_permalink();
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: I came up with a different solution, which I will post in a bit. However, the `get_the_permalink()` function you used helped a lot.

Comment: Happy to hear I could be of service. @NerdOfLinux